# Selenium/python not able to reach certain address

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

```
from selenium import webdriver

def driverInit(url):
    global driver

    # webdriver init
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url) # address
    sleep(2) # time for page load

link = input("enter a url")
driverInit(link)
```

This is my code for accessing the web page. It should work. It works with almost every link I give it except for one link. This link works when I input it into the browser, but when I try to get selenium to do it fails and gives this error. The browser opens up but the page never loads. What can I do to fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abpet/PycharmProjects/yolobot/bot.py", line 27, in <module>
    driverInit(link)
  File "C:/Users/abpet/PycharmProjects/yolobot/bot.py", line 22, in driverInit
    driver.get(url) # address
  File "E:\PYTHON 3.7.3 x86\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "E:\PYTHON 3.7.3 x86\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\PYTHON 3.7.3 x86\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
driver.get(url) # address
```

Is giving the error:

```
invalid argument
```

Something must be wrong with your URL as entered, possibly there is an excess space at the end. Your web browser may be correcting the URL for you, I can only speculate since you haven't provided the URL.